# Can HTML/CSS/JS be used to build a mobile app via compilation through Adobe Air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe, flash-builder

I know that HTML/CSS/JS can be used to write a desktop app for Mac or PC using Adobe Air.  Can the same HTML/CSS/JS code base also be used to compile the project via Adobe Air to run on mobile devices (iPhone specifically)?   Or, must one use Adobe ActionScript?   I seem to haven come up with conflicting answers to this when googling for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use the exact same HTML/CS/JS code base for mobile apps in AIR -- the root file has to be a SWF file. Possibly you could build a StageWebView wrapper that displayed your HTML content, but that is only the case if you don't access AIR APIs in your application (well, there are probably hackish ways to communicate between the wrapper and the HTML content). It might be better to look at something like PhoneGap, which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: I'd like to add this comment suggesting to use the ANE approach when in adobeAir. https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe's documentation you can use HTML/CSS/JavaScript with Adobe AIR but the render method really depends on the device itself:

> On devices in the mobile and extended mobile profiles, the StageWebView class uses the system web control provided by the device operating system. Thus, the available features and rendering appearance may vary from device to device.

*http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html*

I don't think you would even be able to create an app for iPhone with just ActionScript as that would createa SWF and that is not supported on iPhones or any other iDevice.

Comment: You can create an iOS application with ActionScript -- AIR cross-compiles the ActionScript to native code on iOS. What isn't allowed would be to load a SWF into the StageWebView.